# Hypothetical concatenation predicament

Tags: php, string, concatenation

So I am working on a simple micro language/alternative syntax for PHP.
Its syntax takes a lot from JavaScript and CoffeeScript including a few of my own concepts. I have hand written the parser (no parser generator used) in PHP to convert the code into PHP then execute it. It is more of a proof of concept/learning tool rather than anything else but I'd be lying if I said I didn't want to see it used on an actual project one day.

Anyway here is a little problem I have come across that I thought I would impose on you great intellects:

As you know in PHP the period ( . ) is used for string concatenation. However in JavaScript it is used for method chaining.

Now one thing that annoys me in PHP is having to do use that bloody arrow (->) for my method chains, so I went the JavaScript way and implemented the period (.) for use with objects.

(I think you can see the problem already)

Because I'm currently only writing a 'dumb' parser that merely does a huge search and replace, there is no way to distinguish whether a period (.) is being used for concatenation or for method chaining.

"So if you are trying to be like JavaScript, just use the addition (+) operator Franky!", I hear you scream. Well I would but because the addition (+) operator is used for math in PHP I would merely be putting myself in the same situation.

Unless I can make my parser smart enough (with a crap load of work) to know that when the addition (+) operator is working with integers then don't convert it into a period (.) for concatenation I am pretty much screwed.

But here is the cool thing. Because this is pretty much a new language. I don't have to use the period or addition operator for concatenation.

So my question is: If I was to decide to introduce a new method of string concatenation, what character would make the most sense?

Comment: if anyone is interested in the project, I have put it up here: 
https://bitbucket.org/valordigital/dotvee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it have to be one character? `..` could work!

Any myriad of combinations, like `~~` or `>:` even!

Comment: Can't use a comma, how could you determine if a function call with strings was concatenation or a function call? i.e. `foo( "stack", "overflow", "stackoverflow");`

Comment: The double period `..` could work actually. Whatever I choose its bound to annoy someone

Comment: @FrankyChanyau that is true, but this language is for *you*! Choose whatever you wish! see http://github.com/tekknolagi/gecho - i chose whatever operators i wanted :)

Comment: @FrankyChanyau also your last name is awesome

Comment: Just don't choose something like `=[:>)+==<` or `<==####{~~~~` because even though "man in a funny hat" or "two stage rocket in flight" may look like awesome concatenation operators, in practice you'll get tired of typing them.

Comment: @KeithIrwin good suggestion! also, don't use something crazy with brackets, braces, or parens

Comment: @KeithIrwin - you got me! I was going to disregard everything and just go with `8==D`

Comment: @FrankyChanyau if you want to make a joke language that would be hilarious

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use + or ., then I would recommend ^ because that's used in some other languages for string concatenation and I don't believe that it's used for anything in PHP.
**Edit:** It's been pointed out that it's used for XOR.  One option would be to use ^ anyway since bitwise XOR is not commonly used and then to map something else like `^^` to XOR.  Another option would be to use `..` for concatenation.  The problem is that the single characters are mostly taken.

Another option would be to use +, but map it to a function which concatenates when one argument is a string and adds otherwise.  In order to not break things which rely on strings which are numbers being treated as their values, we should probably treat numeric strings as numbers for these purposes.  Here's the function that I would use.

```
function smart_add($arg1,$arg2) {
    if ($arg1.is_numeric() && $arg2.is_numeric()) {
        return $arg1 + $arg2;
    } else {
        return $arg1 . $arg2;
    }
}
```

Then `a + b + c + d` just gets turned into `smart_add(smart_add(smart_add(a,b),c),d)`

This may not be perfect in all cases, but it should work pretty well most of the time and has clear rules for use.

Comment: It's the [XOR](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) operator.

Comment: Ah, sorry, then.  I know it's used as such in C, Java, etc. as XOR, but when I googled for lists of php operators, the page I found left that out.  I do have an alternate, more complex solution, too.  It'll be added to the post via edit in a moment.

Comment: The downvote was probably for the original post before I added the edits, which just suggested ^.  It wasn't as good an idea as I thought due to the use of ^ for XOR (darn webschools not noting that their list of php operators was incomplete).  I had the plan of adding the smart_add code to the answer all along, but it took me a little bit to get that part together.

Comment: The `smart_add()` seems like the best option if I choose to stay conventional. Wow so many choices, to think this was actually frustrating me a week ago

Comment: Oh, that's a pity but at least someone balanced it out!

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is: If I was to decide to introduce a new method of
>   string concatenation, what character would make the most sense?

As you're well aware of, you'll need to chose a character that is not being used as one of PHP's [operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php). Since string concatenation is a common technique, I would try to avoid using characters that you need to press `SHIFT` to type, as those characters will be a hindrance.

Instead of trying to assign one character for string concatenation (as most are already in use), perhaps you should define your own syntax for string concatenation (or any other operation you need to overwrite with a different operator), as a shorthand operator (sort of). Something like:

```
[$string, $string]
```

Should be easy to pick up by a parser and form the resulting concatenated string.

**Edit:** I should also note that whether you're using literal strings or variables, there's no way (as far as I know) to confuse this syntax with any other PHP functionality, since the comma in the middle is invalid for array manipulations. So, all of the following would still be recognized as string concatenation and not *something else* in PHP.

```
["stack", "overflow"]
["stack", $overflow]
[$stack, $overflow]
```

**Edit:** Since this conflicts to JSON notation, the following alternative variations exist:

1. Changing the delimiter
2. Omitting the delimiter

Example:

```
[$stack $overflow $string $concatenation] // Use nothing (but really need space)
```

Comment: I like where that is going. The only problem is I have also gone the JavaScript route with my array syntax. Arrays are pretty much written as JSON objects. So `[string, string]` converts to `array($string, $string)` same with using `{...}` for multidimensional arrays.

Comment: @FrankyChanyau - If the comma was omitted, it wouldn't be valid PHP syntax and could be used to represent string concatenation. Are there any conflicts with using the same syntax with the comma removed (i.e. using a space character as the delimiter)?

Comment: are you proposing something similar to `[stringOne "another string" stringTwo stringThree]`? Hmm, I will try that out and get back to you, I am worried that If I was to scan through the code really quickly I may confuse a concatenated string for an array. With that said in the long run for a concatenation of more than two strings it would save a few characters and it would also be a great way to group concatenated strings.

Comment: Yes, or you can change the delimiter to something else! `:)`